# How Do You Combine Scale and Translation Animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, translation, scale, cgaffinetransform

I am attempting to do an UIView animation where my image starts at the top left of the screen and expands to the original size and place in the middle of the screen. So far I have been able to make it do this separately but when I try to combine these animations it will only do the scale animation.

Is there a way I can make this work with **Scale and Translation at the same time**?

Here is what I have so far:

```
CGAffineTransform setpointTrans = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-200.0f, -200.0f);
CGAffineTransform setpointScale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.0f, 0.0f);
_RSEImage.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(setpointTrans, setpointScale);
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:5];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
CGAffineTransform scaleTrans  = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 1.0f);
CGAffineTransform lefttorightTrans  = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0f,0.0f);
_RSEImage.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(scaleTrans, lefttorightTrans);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Ok I figured it out, here is what I changed:

```
_RSEImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.0f, 0.0f);
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:5];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
CGAffineTransform scaleTrans  = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 1.0f);
CGAffineTransform lefttorightTrans  = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(200.0f,200.0f);
_RSEImage.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(scaleTrans, lefttorightTrans);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: I tried out your code and it perfectly does what you would like achieve: scale up and translate...  What is the origin point of the RESImage before this code?

Comment: x 160 y 242, i guess thats what you are asking, sorry this is my first iphone app. The image size is 161 x 71

Comment: It is hard to tell from this code where you have the problem because basically this code snippet is working, this is the way you do affine transformation "merging". So I guess some other part of your code prevents somehow translation, or not visible... Start adding the functions gradually by commenting out things, and check that until that point everything is lookin fine. Eg. check this snippet for the first 3 line with 0.3f scale and -100f translation - you see the img? then add translation alone to test out the params,then merge with scale.. You can use my answer too since blocks are easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this, animation blocks, also (from iOS4):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 5
                      delay: 0
                    options: (UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
                 animations:^{_RSEImage.center = CGPointMake(300, 300) ; _RSEImage.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 2.0, 2.0);}
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) { }
 ];
```

Relevant official doc here: [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/animatingviews/animatingviews.html)

Nice tutorial there: [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/how-to-use-uiview-animation-tutorial)

*Hope it helps!*

Comment: that just scaled the image to twice its size, it still didn't move the image from the left upper corner to the middle.

Comment: Sthing weird happening... ;-) What is the type of _RSEImage, can u share the code how you add to the view? or any other code related to _RSEImage?

Comment: I figured it out and edited my question, I will learn these blocks, it seems a lot easier. Thank you for your help.